# Typescript enum gives wrong type to the variable?

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have the enum:

```
export enum AlgorithmEnum {
    SHA1,
    SHA256,
    SHA512
}
```

I use it for the property Algorithm of a class:

```
export class Authenticator {
    Type: Type = Type.TOTP;
    Icon: string = '';
    Issuer: string = '';
    Username: string = '';
    Secret: string = '';
    Pin: null = null;
    Algorithm: AlgorithmEnum = AlgorithmEnum.SHA1;
    Digits: number = 6;
    Period: number = 30;
    Counter: number = 0;
    CopyCount: number = 0;
    Ranking: number = 0;

    constructor() {

    }
}
```

Then in one of the components I try to use it with the switch:

```
exportUriList() {
    const authData = this.authDataService.authData;
    let uriList: string[] = [];

    authData.Authenticators.forEach(auth => {
      //otpauth://totp/IBM%20Security%20Verify:@USER_NAME@?secret=@SECRET_KEY@&issuer=IBM%20Security%20Verify&algorithm=@ALGORITHM@

      let issuerAndUsername = `${auth.Issuer}:${auth.Username}`;
      let secret = `?secret=${auth.Secret}`;
      let issuer = `&issuer=${auth.Issuer}`;
      let algorithm = '';

      if (auth.Algorithm) {

        switch (auth.Algorithm) {
          case AlgorithmEnum.SHA1:
            break;
          case AlgorithmEnum.SHA256:
            break;
          case AlgorithmEnum.SHA512:
            break;
        }

        algorithm = `&algorithm=${auth.Algorithm}`;
      }

      let uri = 'otpauth://totp/';

    });
}
```

Seems like should work, right? It doesn't:
[image]
Why I get this error? It looks like typescript missed one of the enums and there is no proper type?

```
Type 'AlgorithmEnum.SHA1' is not comparable to type 'AlgorithmEnum.SHA256 | AlgorithmEnum.SHA512'.
```

Comment: Need more code to determine the cause of this

Comment: Added more code (The function exportUriList() is unfinished, don't worry about that)

Comment: I have a feeling that it must be some typescript bug, because it missed one type without a logical reason. When I use `number` for property instead of `AlgorithmEnum` then it works.

Comment: `if (auth.Algorithm)` - As per your definition, this does nothing because `Algorithm` is by default set to `AlgorithmEnum.SHA1` in your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code explicitly filters out the value SHA1 because of the condition marked by the comment:

```js
exportUriList() {
    const authData = this.authDataService.authData;
    let uriList: string[] = [];

    authData.Authenticators.forEach(auth => {
      //otpauth://totp/IBM%20Security%20Verify:@USER_NAME@?secret=@SECRET_KEY@&issuer=IBM%20Security%20Verify&algorithm=@ALGORITHM@

      let issuerAndUsername = `${auth.Issuer}:${auth.Username}`;
      let secret = `?secret=${auth.Secret}`;
      let issuer = `&issuer=${auth.Issuer}`;
      let algorithm = '';

      // THIS FILTERS OUT THE VALUE 0, WHICH IS SHA1
      if (auth.Algorithm) {

        switch (auth.Algorithm) {
          case AlgorithmEnum.SHA1:
            break;
          case AlgorithmEnum.SHA256:
            break;
          case AlgorithmEnum.SHA512:
            break;
        }

        algorithm = `&algorithm=${auth.Algorithm}`;
      }

      let uri = 'otpauth://totp/';

    });
}
```

This is the case because SHA1 in the enum gets the numeric value 0 assigned. In an if condition, the numeric value 0 (like an empty string) evaluates to false. So TypeScript narrows the type down to exclude SHA1.

Change the if condition to

```js
if (typeof auth.Algorithm === "number") {
```

instead.

Comment: I discovered that it's because of that condition in the moment you wrote your answer :D Well done to notice that without having the code in the IDE, thanks! Best answer. JS can sometimes surprise.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the AlgorithmEnum enum is defined without explicit numeric values, so AlgorithmEnum.SHA1 will have the numeric value 0, AlgorithmEnum.SHA256 will have 1, and AlgorithmEnum.SHA512 will have 2. So just change your enum to:

```
enum AlgorithmEnum {
  SHA1 = 'SHA1',
  SHA256 = 'SHA256',
  SHA512 = 'SHA512',
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not the case (pun not intended), the error is still the same.

Comment: I changed the answer. Previous one was posted before I saw the changes to the code that you posted. Now it should help.

Comment: They must be numeric values by design, I can't change it to a string. (although I checked and it worked)